# Return value from the row below when condition is met in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm very new to Python and I'm trying to figure out a way to pick certain "cells" from a pandas DataFrame when certain conditions are met. To give an example, say you have this type of data:

```
Number Country
1      Germany
2      Italy
0      Spain
0.5    Greece
```

I'm looking to add another column with the country from the row below of the one where the condition is met. If this was in excel assuming "Number" is cell A1 the formula would be: *=if(A2>0,B3,"")*

so that the answer would be:

```
Number Country  New Column
1      Germany  Italy
2      Italy    Spain
0      Spain
0.5    Greece
```

how would you do this on a pandas dataframe?

I tried to do it using:

```
df["New Column"] = np.where(df["Number"] > 0.5, df["Country"], "")
```

but that doesn't give the country that's one row below.

Comment: you could use `shift()` to create new column with all values from previous rows and later remove values which doesn't met some rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there, just `shift` the index by a required/set number of periods as the True result  and `np.nan` or white space `" "` for false within the `np.where` expression

```
df["New Column"] = np.where(df["Number"] > 0.5, df.Country.shift(-1)," ")
print(df)



   Number  Country New Column
0     1.0  Germany      Italy
1     2.0    Italy      Spain
2     0.0    Spain           
3     0.5   Greece
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
df["New Column"] = np.where(df.Number>0.5, df.Country.shift(-1),np.nan)
print(df["New Column"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shift(-1)` to create column with values from previous rows

```
df['New Column'] = df['Country'].shift(-1)
```

and later use rule which removes some values

```
df.loc[ df["Number"] <= 0.5, "New Column"] = ""
```

---

Minimal working code

```
text = '''Number Country
1      Germany
2      Italy
0      Spain
0.5    Greece'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+')

df['New Column'] = df['Country'].shift(-1)
print(df)

df.loc[ df["Number"] <= 0.5, "New Column"] = ""
print(df)
```

Result

```
   Number  Country New Column
0     1.0  Germany      Italy
1     2.0    Italy      Spain
2     0.0    Spain     Greece
3     0.5   Greece        NaN

   Number  Country New Column
0     1.0  Germany      Italy
1     2.0    Italy      Spain
2     0.0    Spain           
3     0.5   Greece
```